# Vauxhall Zafira running lumpy

Tags: vauxhall

Good morning all,

So i bought a Zafira, 1.6 Eco tec and all was perfect when i bought it. No fault codes, brand new oil etc etc. started driving it home and got about 5 miles and it starts to jump around, i checked the codes and i got P0300, P0301, P0302, P0303, P0304 so bassicly all 4 clinders miss fireing. Ive changed the spark plugs, coil pack, EGR valve, cleaned the Air Mass Flow and check the pressure in the cylinders and still no luck. i tried to get my money back but the guy is refusing so im stuck with this car, has anyone else has a simular issue?

Comment: Has it been refuelled with the incorrect fuel?

Comment: Nope, its only had petrol and when we bought it. You can smell the petrol too.

Comment: Connect a computer to it and check if you are getting reasonable MAF and MAP sensor values.

Comment: Map is 11.5 and MAF is 0.681 and that's on idle I checked it all but I can't upload the images from the check :)